# Teamcity Visual Studios Addin

Tags: teamcity

We have a ssh based svn access. We were using the team city VS addin for remote runs without checking in post run as this failed due to the addin not supporting ssh pre version 6.5.
after upgrading to version 6.5 this has stopped working and has started giving us the following error -

Error while checking for incoming Subversion changes. svn: Can't create tunnel: The system cannot find the file specified..

Svn has exited with code '1'.

svn status

-even though we dont use post run commit!

Has anyone else had this issue!

BR
Niladri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Edit the file `c:\Documents and Settings\<USER>\Application Data\Subversion\config`
- Locate the section named `[tunnels]`
- Add the following line:

  ```
  ssh=c:/path/to/plink.exe -i c:/path/to/your/key.ppk
  ```

Comment: cant find the config file for svn in appdata? is there any other place it could be in?

Comment: In a Windows 7 machine, I found it in `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Subversion`.